# Error with Boot 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT using Gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I created a Gradle boot project with version 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from https://start.spring.io and did not make any changes, and tried to just run the app using:

**gradle bootRun**

I get the following errors

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator//spring-boot-starter-actuator-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator//spring-boot-starter-actuator-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator//spring-boot-starter-actuator-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator//spring-boot-starter-actuator-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator//spring-boot-starter-actuator-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator//spring-boot-starter-actuator-.jar
```

Now, when I change the version to:
***springBootVersion = '1.5.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'*** the app starts up fine.

I suspect there is something wrong with the dependency management **${springBootVersion}** tag, as seen:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/**[WHERE IS THE VERSION???]**/spring-boot-starter-actuator-**[WHERE IS THE VERSION???]**.pom

Here are the repos I have configured (the bold one was NOT aut generated by INITIALZR:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
```

That might have helped with some of the dependencies, but there is still an issue with the starter pom's:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop//spring-boot-starter-aop-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop//spring-boot-starter-aop-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop//spring-boot-starter-aop-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop//spring-boot-starter-aop-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop//spring-boot-starter-aop-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop//spring-boot-starter-aop-.jar
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc//spring-boot-starter-jdbc-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc//spring-boot-starter-jdbc-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc//spring-boot-starter-jdbc-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc//spring-boot-starter-jdbc-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc//spring-boot-starter-jdbc-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc//spring-boot-starter-jdbc-.jar
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest//spring-boot-starter-data-rest-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest//spring-boot-starter-data-rest-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest//spring-boot-starter-data-rest-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest//spring-boot-starter-data-rest-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest//spring-boot-starter-data-rest-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest//spring-boot-starter-data-rest-.jar
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find com.h2database:h2:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2//h2-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2//h2-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/com/h2database/h2//h2-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/com/h2database/h2//h2-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/h2database/h2//h2-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/h2database/h2//h2-.jar
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find org.hsqldb:hsqldb:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb//hsqldb-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb//hsqldb-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/hsqldb/hsqldb//hsqldb-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/hsqldb/hsqldb//hsqldb-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/hsqldb/hsqldb//hsqldb-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/hsqldb/hsqldb//hsqldb-.jar
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security//spring-boot-starter-security-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security//spring-boot-starter-security-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security//spring-boot-starter-security-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security//spring-boot-starter-security-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security//spring-boot-starter-security-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security//spring-boot-starter-security-.jar
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.jar
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.pom
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.jar
```

Comment: Post your whole build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
maven {
    url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot'
}
```

To your repositories block (both main and buildscript)

Comment: That might have helped with some of the dependencies, but there is still an issue with the starter pom's:

Comment: I had it in both. The issue is with the starters that are in those REPO's. They are wrong: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/[VERSION MISSING]/spring-boot-starter-aop-[VERSION MISSING].pom

Comment: BUILD-SNAPSHOT versions are not in the maven central. You're looking in the wrong place. Look here: https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/